# Configure "dynamic" command line arguments in sbt-native-packager

Tags: bash, scala, sbt, jmx, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to append command line arguments to the standard script generated by sbt-native-packager but I can't figure out how to get the behaviour I want having read the docs.

Basically, I want to add something like this to my `applicaiton.ini` file.

```
-server
-J-Xms256m
-J-Xmx512m
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(getIpAddress)
```

All good so far but you may have noticed the **`$(getIpAddress)`**. I want a value assigned here from a function that'll run on the host machine.

I can add the function `getIpAddress` to the script template with:

```
bashScriptExtraDefines ++= 
   IO.readLines(sourceDirectory.value / "scripts" / "find_ip.sh")
```

So the content gets appended to the runner script like this:

```
getIpAddress() {
    echo 10.0.1.23 .  # impl snipped for brevity
}

# java_cmd is overrode in process_args when -java-home is used
declare java_cmd=$(get_java_cmd)

# if configuration files exist, prepend their contents to $@ so it can be processed by this runner
[[ -f "$script_conf_file" ]] && set -- $(loadConfigFile "$script_conf_file") "$@"

run "$@"
```

The `set -- $(loadConfigFile "$script_conf_file") "$@"` bit is prepending the java command with the content of my `application.ini` but it wont evaluate the function.

So, I get that the contents is prepended to the java command with `--` but I **don't know if I can get it to evaluate `$(getIpAddress)`**. When I execute the script, the output looks like this, showing it's not calling the function. I need the resolved value here.

```
$ ./my-app -v
# Executing command line:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(getIpAddress)
-cp
/Users/toby/my-app.jar
my.app.Main
-serve
```

Is there alternative ways to achieve the same thing -- adding more "dynamic" values to the generated script? Have I got my bash commands wrong? :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments in the INI file won't get expanded. You could add it to the script instead:

```
bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(getIpAddress)""""
```